# remove application icons in dashboard

Tags: exist-db

I deleted a collection in exist-db, but the application icon still appears on exist-db dashboard.

when click on it, it return HTTP ERROR 404. this is normal because I deleted it, so the icon on dashboard is no longer necessary.

how to delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the package manager in the dashboard to properly uninstall the application package. A package may contain library modules and other components which are not removed if you delete the collection.